# Get wrong IP address when using bind() in C

Tags: c++, c, sockets, tcp

I'm using socket programing APIs in C. In a TCP client-side program, I use `bind()`, and then use `getsockname()` (before calling `connect()`) to get the local machine's IP address and port number. However, I can only get the correct port number, while getting a wrong IP address (a zero).

So I'm asking if there is any way to correctly get a correct IP address for local machine (before calling `connect()`)?

Comment: Can you show how you bind the socket?

Comment: It would help a lot if you tell us why do you need the local IP address.

Comment: This all depends on how you bind() the socket. Show that code. If you use INADDR_ANY, you'll get that back when you call getsockname() before connect(). If you call getsockname() after the connect(), you'll get the local IP used for the communication. @Juliano That doesn't seem very relevant, there's many uses for learning the local address(Though, AFTER communication is etablished)

Comment: @nos good point about calling `getsockname()` _after_ connecting.

Comment: @nos Really, what uses? (think about NAT, and how it breaks whatever you think that the local IP address may have any use).

Comment: @Juliano Not everyone develops code for the internet, or other places where NAT is a concern (you might even need that address to do an automatic UPnP query to open up a NAT gateway) . And there's many protocols that require you to communicate the local IP used.   You might want the address just for local debug/logging use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A portable way to do it would be to first call gethostname() then follow with a call to gethostbyname().

ie.

```
char hostname[256], ipaddress[256];
if (gethostname(hostname, sizeof(hostname)) != SOCKET_ERROR) {
    struct hostent *phe = gethostbyname(hostname);
    if (phe != NULL && phe->h_addr_list[0] != NULL) {
        struct in_addr addr;
        memcpy(&addr, phe->h_addr_list[0], sizeof(struct in_addr));
        strcpy(ipaddress, inet_ntoa(addr));
    }
}
```

Comment: A `for` construct that ends in a `break` statement, and have no `continue` anywhere?

Comment: if your local host file or DNS is inconsistent this will fail.  The preferred approach is to use the OS-dependent method to enumerate the individual network interfaces.

Comment: @Alnitak, yes agreed. flyingbin asked a simple question and I provided an answer that seemed to suit his immediate needs.

Answer (score 4):

There is not a simple or portable way to do what you are trying to do. The behavior of `bind()` and `getsockname()` in your case is correct.

Your program should not depend or require the IP address of the host in any way. If it does, you probably have some design problem in your program.

Ask yourself what is the IP address of a computer with two network interfaces, connected to two different networks and multiple IP addresses?

```
     Network 1                  Network 2
...-----------+--            --+-----------...
               \              /
     192.0.2.1  \            /  198.51.100.2
          eth0  +------------+  eth1
                |  Computer  |
                +------------+
```

**Q:** What IP address you expect to see in this case?

The answer is that there is no right answer, and your program should not even bother with this. Your program should be more concerned about establishing a communication, and for that you only need the target IP or hostname. The operating system will find a way to establish communication (and for connection-oriented streams, it *may* be able to give you the local address that was chosen to communicate with that target).

You may retrieve the current hostname using [`gethostname()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gethostname), and with that name you may try to find the IP address, but there are still a lot of gotchas:

1. It is not required or guaranteed that the hostname has any associated IP address.
2. In many more cases than you think, the IP address associated with the hostname is 127.0.0.1, which is not useful (most Linux distros add this to your /etc/hosts file).
3. Even if you get an IP address from the hostname, it is unlikely that it will be of any use (like case 2 above, or a local IP address behind a NAT, or the IP of the wrong network interface).

So, you should not be relying on this information in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`gethostname`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gethostname) to get the hostname, and then use [`gethostbyname`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/gethostbyname) to get the IP-addresses.

Comment: Not 100% reliably, though.  `gethostbyname()` does a DNS lookup, so it may end up returning something you are not expecting if the `hostname` has extra DNS entries associated with it (load balancing, etc).

Answer (score 1):

If you're binding to `INADDR_ANY`, then that's the address you'll get out of `getsockname()`.

In particular, on a machine with multiple interfaces the address used by your side of the socket will depend on the routing table and the remote client's address.

For example if you connect to yourself on the loopback interface you'd be on `127.0.0.1`, whereas if you connect to someone outside then it will be (one of) your ethernet interface's addresses.

The correct approach **if and only if you really need to bind on a known address** is to enumerate your machine's network interfaces (see `man netdevice` if you're on Linux) and then supply the specific desired address to `bind()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `gethostip()` to obtain the host IP address.

Comment: There is a Linux-specific command `gethostip`, but no C function with such name anywhere. Perhaps you meant `gethostname()` ?